# Dynamic StyleUrl Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, less, angular7

Which way is better for dynamic load style in angular 7
i use for example of this way but not working in version 7 angular
in addition this code working in version lower angular 7
help me , thanks

```
function theme(): string[] {
  // return ['./app.component.less'] >> not find
     return ['/app.component.less']
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: theme()
})
```

Comment: take a look here:https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/

Comment: thanks thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 4):

You must give link for styleURLs. Here I update your code. Please have look.

For more details you can go through with given link [Angular7 Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

```
function theme(): string[] {
  // return ['./app.component.less'] >> not find
     return ['/app.component.less']
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```